# Find \n while looping through string

Tags: javascript, string, text, line-breaks

My script should do something certain with a string if it bumps into a line break `\n` while looping through it.

Basically, I could just use `if(myText[i] == "…")`, but it doesn't find `\n`s this way …

---

The background: In order to make the user selection not "disturbed" by `<br/>`s, the whole text should be converted into something like:

`<span text-from="0" text-to="4">ABCDE</span><br/><span text-from="5" text-to="8">FGHI</span>`

Comment: Why not [just do a normal search and replace in the string instead of looping through it?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Actually, lookint at the code - does it *need* to have the from and to attributes? If so, it might be easier to split the string on new lines, process the results wrapping them in spans and then join them back using `br` tags.

Comment: Are you looking for actual newline or the escaped newline? Ie one would be `myText[i] == "\n"` vs `myText[i]=="\\" && myText[i+1]=="n"`

Comment: What @PatrickEvans says is also true - a new line is actually a single character, despite being expressed as `\n`. Unless the string literally contains the characters "\" followed by "n" you wouldn't expect there to be multiple characters.

Comment: @vlaz That doesn't work because I have some more complex work to do with the string...

Comment: @ÖromLoidl which suggestion doesn't work? Because I am not sure what makes either impossible.

Comment: @vlaz The one with `replace`. But the one with `if(altext[i] == "\n")` seems to do now, thanks!